# Stopping Parallel.For further thread execution, but allowing current threads to finish

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.for

I have a program that uses `Parallel.For` and iterates through 1000+ iterations sometimes. I want to cut off the program from running at 7 PM. I want to stop any new threads from running and exit the program. However, I will be generous and allow current running threads to finish. How can I do this?

I looked at `loopState` and I do not want to just kill the whole program. It seems that with `loopState.Break`, depending on which thread saw that is was 7 PM, all threads up to that one would run. So if thread 500 just happened to be running and saw it was 7PM it would stop. If threads 400-499 had not run yet they would execute. Is that right?

Would a `CancellationToken` be the way to go with this?

Would it be easier to just stop all threads at 7 and pick it up later? The processing can recover and redo anything the current running threads were doing.

Comment: Kinda stupid maybe, but why don't you add a check at the beginning of the code block scheduled inside `parallel.for`? So that when a new execution starts it checks for a condition (e.g. 7 pm) and only proceeds when allowed

Comment: Why are you using `Parallel.For`? And what exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: zaitsman - You're right. It would be easier. I (my boss) was just wanting something that would not cause the program to go through all the iterations, though it would be very fast. I think I will just do it this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`ParallelLoopState.Stop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.stop):

> Calling the `Stop` method indicates that any iterations of the loop that have not yet started need not be run. It effectively cancels any additional iterations of the loop. However, it does not stop any iterations that have already begun execution.

This implies that you will be checking the condition `if clock >= 7 PM` in each iteration, which has some overhead. A more efficient way to do it is to use a timer-based [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource):

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new();

ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount,
    CancellationToken = cts.Token
};

TimeSpan timeSpan = // Calculate the time-span between now and 7 PM
cts.CancelAfter(timeSpan);

try
{
    Parallel.For(0, 1000, parallelOptions, index =>
    {
        //...
    });
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    // Timed-out
}
```